# Android: How to extract data from GridView?

Tags: android

Hi all
I have a GridView of FrameLayout made of an image and textview. I want to get the corresponding image and the text when I click a cell of Grid. Mentioned that textview is top of image.

Does anybody have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First register item click listener of grid view 
e.g. gridview.setOnItemClickListener(gridItemClickListener);

Then

```
   OnItemClickListener gridItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListner() 
    {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

   {

      // here you will get your clicked cell of grid and you can find the image and text.
      ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_raw_image);
      TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_raw_text);  
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the viewHolder technique as recommended by google, use:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListner()
  {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
    ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    //use the views you hold in the viewHolder
    ...
    }
  });
```